# Adicionar action e onClick num commandButton

Tags: html5, jsf, java-ee

Boa tarde, estou construindo um sistema javaWeb, gostaria de saber se eu posso adicionar uma Action e um onClick num commandButton?

```
h:commandButton value="Reservar" action="#{aluguelController.reservarEtios}" onClick="chamaTela();" styleclass="btn btn-primary"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é o que você precisa, mas fiz algo nesse sentido:

[image: Dialog de confirmação]

```
  <p:commandButton value="Reserva" action="#{locadoraBean.reservarVeiculo}" oncomplete="PF('reserva').show();" />   

    <p:dialog id="mod" modal="true" widgetVar="reserva"
        header="Confirmação da Reserva" draggable="false" closable="true" autoUpdate="true">
        <h:form id="rent-car-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

<p:panelGrid columns="2">

<f:facet name="header">
    <p:graphicImage url="/RESOURCES/images/background/toyota_etios.png" />
</f:facet>

<h:outputText value="Veículo:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
<h:outputText value="Toyota Etios" />

<h:outputText value="Ano/Modelo:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
<h:outputText value="2018/2019" />

<h:outputText value="Cor:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
<h:outputText value="Prata" />

<h:outputText value="Placa:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
<h:outputText value="XXX-0000" />

<h:outputText value="Combustível:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
<h:outputText value="Flex" />

<h:outputText value="Reservado em nome:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
<h:outputText value="Fulano de Tal" />

<h:outputText value="Retirada prevista:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
<h:outputText value="14/06/2019 12:15:00" />

 <h:outputText value="Devolução prevista:" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
<h:outputText value="18/06/2019 12:15:00" />   

 </p:panelGrid> 
    </div>
       </h:form>
          </p:dialog>
```

No exemplo acima, o método **reservarVeiculo** não está fazendo nada, apenas exemplificando, porque criei um **dialog** com dados **estáticos**. Pelo que entendi você quer realizar a ação de um botão, logo após chamar uma tela, então quando você escolher as informações da reserva e clicar em **Reservar**, a reserva deverá ser efetuada e em seguida deverá surgir uma tela com as informações da reserva efetuada.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa só perguntar novamente.

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta. Eu consegui fazer o método funcionar sem o javascript, no caso dentro do método em Java reservarEtios eu coloquei um return com o nome da outra página, ai ele faz o redirecionamento. Agora, você saberia me dizer se em java tem como eu capturar o id desse botão que chama o método? Obrigado novamente

Comment: Acredito que sim, mas qual finalidade seria?

Comment: Porque eu preciso de um metodo que passe para classe DAO o ID do carro, cada botao equivale a um carro então cada um tem um ID, eu gostaria de passar esse ID.